# Can I limit the size of the Title and Content fields in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

Is there a way to limit the size of the Title and Content fields in Alfresco? (I know how to add constraints to my own fields, but not these ones.)

Comment: Sure, there are ways to do this, but applying these constraints to all instances of cm:content and cm:titled does not sound like a good idea. Why would you want to do this in the first place ?

Comment: Do you want to do this for all cm:content, or just certain ones (eg with a different, custom aspect on them)?

Comment: @AndreasSteffan The purpose of the CMS is only to feed content into a separate application. We are not going to allow arbitrary content.

Comment: @Gagravarr I would want it to apply to all content that has a certain aspect applied to it. (This aspect is auto-applied when content is created in the folder.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Forms engine, you could define your own control. Check the [wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms#Configuring_Controls) for how to set it up.

You could start by copying the textfield.ftl control and set a length max or a nice JavaScript max. You could even add something fancy with a mouse over that will show an info that the max characters are x.

Comment: Ugh, that looks painful. Powerful, but painful. Guess its time to start studying.

Comment: Hi, it's not that hard. Just check the textfield.ftl. It's just a piece of html wrapped in Freemarker. Just limit the input type text

Comment: Thanks. That one comment made more sense than all of the documentation I've read thus far.